# How to remove amplify AdminQueries API

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I'm working on a Reactjs project that has amplify authentication with Cognito. I was trying to make admin actions with AdminQueries API. I created a AdminQuery API and now i want to completely remove from my amplify profile and add again a new adminQuery API.how to do that?

I tried using amplify update auth and creating new adminQueries Api. but still is says no changes are made.

Comment: You can remove the AdminQueries API by first running the cli command to remove the api 'amplify remove api' and then select the AdminQueries api, Afterwards, remove the lambda function associated to it by running the cli command 'amplify remove function' and select the admin query function